# How to enable Grommet sidebar menu within split on mobile

Tags: grommet

Hi I'm new to Grommet and development in general. I'm having some trouble with displaying a mobile menu.

When a screen hits a certain size the split view shows only the right side of the screen, giving you no access to the menu.

```
<App centered={false}>
  <Split separator={true} flex='right' fixed={true} colorIndex='brand'>
    <Sidebar colorIndex='brand' responsive={true}>
      <Header pad='small' justify='between'>
        <Title> brand </Title>
      </Header>
      <Box flex='grow' justify='start'>
        <Menu primary={true}>
          <Anchor key="home" path="/app" label="Home" />
        </Menu>
      </Box>
    </Sidebar>
    <Box>
      {this.props.children}
    </Box>
  </Split>
</App>
```

From what I can tell you just need a title in a header on the right side that is set to `responsive={true}`. This will display your heading if your device is a mobile.

```
<div>
  <Header pad='small' justify='between' responsive={true}>
    <Title> brand </Title>
  </Header>
  <Cards />
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to work. The header displays the whole time. What I ideally want is to display the header from the sidebar.

Can anyone please help me achieve this?